# remove ununique instance from master sheet

Tags: excel, vba

ive got an excel workbook with 3 sheets. The sheets all contain lists of names, all the lists overlap at some points becuase they are from different sources.

Im trying to make sheet 1 a unique list, ie. a so that it will only contain names that are not present in sheet2 and sheet3.

I was pointed in the direction of using data > remove duplicates, but this didnt for across sheets, is there a way this could be done using vba macros ?

Comment: ...removing duplicates doesn't seem to address your problem. Do you want to remove any names from `sheet 1` that occur in either `sheet 2` or `sheet 3` ?

Comment: yeah, exactly as you've said

Comment: have you attempted any VBA? - can you add it to the question please?

Comment: I've attempted a solution: depends if you are happy adding extra columns next to the table in `Sheet 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just have a couple of columns down the side of the table in `Sheet 1` that use `VLOOKUP` into sheets 2 and 3 - if it finds a match then it should return 1 otherwise 0.
Then an excel routine would just scan those two columns for 1's - if it finds one then it deletes the row.

Here's an example of the formula I'm talking about:

[image]

Suppose `column D` would then just be the sum of `B` and `C`.

Macro could just then run down column D looking for any values that are `>0`

Not really best practice doing an operation on a collection from within a loop but something like the following loops down over the cells deleting rows as it goes:

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteRows()

Dim i As Integer
i = 2
Do
    If Cells(i, 4) > 0 Then
        Cells(i, 4).EntireRow.Delete xlUp
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 4)) = True

End Sub
```

An alternative would be to load all the names from `sheet 2` and `sheet 3` into an `array`. then come back to `sheet 1` and for each name run through the array testing if it equals any of the values and if it does delete the entirerow. So to use arrays it'd be something like the following ; this assumes each list is in `column A` and starts in `row 2`...

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim names() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1

    'add names from sheet 2 into the array
    Do
        ReDim Preserve names(i)
        names(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i + 1, 1)
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i + 1, 1)) = True

    'add names from sheet 3 into the array
    Do
        ReDim Preserve names(i)
        names(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i + 1, 1)
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i + 1, 1)) = True

    'use the names array to test each row in sheet 1
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 2
    Do

        Dim deleteOccured As Boolean
        deleteOccured = False

        Dim x
        For Each x In names
            If x = Cells(j, 1) Then
                Cells(j, 1).EntireRow.Delete xlUp
                deleteOccured = True
            End If
        Next x

        If deleteOccured = False Then
            j = j + 1
        End If
        deleteOccured = False

    Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(j, 1)) = True

End Sub
```

**WARNING** *I need to stress that these Loops are not perfect: a general best practice of any coding is that you should never loop over an array while doing an operation on the same array from within that loop .....I'm hoping someone will help me out with this.*

Comment: @SiddharthRout ......can you help me with these loops; I've added my warning to the bottom of the answer.